# Using API data to set initial state in the state variable

Tags: reactjs

My images.js file gets the data (basically image is what I am looking at the moment) from the API. This Image component passes state variable (i.e. API data) as props to the ImageSlider component. The ImageSlider component needs to render the 1st image from the props. This is where the problem comes, as the values are not rendered at the initial loading.

Images.js file is:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";

import ImageSlider_1 from "./ImageSlider_1";

const url = "https://hp-api.onrender.com/api/characters";

function Images() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
         const fetchCharacters = async () => {
         try {
              const response = await axios(url);
              const data = await response.data;

              data.map((character) => {
                   if (character.image.localeCompare("")) {
                        setCharacters((characters) => [...characters, character]);
                   }
              });
         } catch (error) {
              setIsError(true);
              console.log(error);
         }
         setIsLoading(false);
   };
   fetchCharacters();
   }, []);

return (
    <Wrapper>
         <ImageSlider_1 characters={characters} />
    </Wrapper>
);
}

const Wrapper = styled.section``;
export default Images;
```

ImageSlider_1js code is:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

function ImageSlider_1({ characters }) {
  console.log(characters[0]?.image);

  const [sliderData, setSliderData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSliderData(characters[0]?.image ?? null);
  }, [characters]);

  const clickHandler = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    const slider = characters.filter((character) => {
      return character.id === id;
    });
    setSliderData(slider);
    console.log(slider);
  };

  // console.log(sliderData);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {sliderData?.image ? (
        <img
          src={sliderData.image}
          alt={sliderData.name}
          className="main-image"
        />
      ) : (
        <img src="logo192.png" />
      )}

      {/* <img
        src={sliderData.image}
        alt={sliderData.name}
        className="main-image"
      /> */}
      {characters.map((character) => {
        return (
          <img
            src={character.image}
            alt={character.name}
            onClick={() => clickHandler(character.id)}
            key={character.id}
            className="images"
          />
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  .main-image {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
  }

  .images {
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    /* width: 100px; */
    object-fit: contain;
  }
`;

export default ImageSlider_1;
```

What I wanted to do is, Inside the , I want to include:

```
<img
    src={sliderData.image}
    alt={sliderData.name}
    className="main-image"
/>
```

But since the sliderData.image, sliderData.name are undefined, I end up doing:

```
{sliderData?.image ? (
   <img
       src={sliderData.image}
       alt={sliderData.name}
       className="main-image"
     />
   ) : (
   <img src="logo192.png" />
)}
```

But the issue now are:
(1) The logo192.png does not change to any image, which I want to change upon clicking any image.
(2) I do not want to use any outside image (like logo192.png) but just the image from the API.

If this even doable without using redux? Please let me know what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: From your title "Using API data to set initial state in the state variable", this isn't possible because the data from the API isn't available at the moment you need to set the initial state.

Comment: With that said, I recommend that you create a new component, possibly in a separate React project, that focuses only on the question you are trying to ask here. The code you show has some extra things that are completely unrelated to your question. For example, you have a `clickHandler()` function that has nothing to do with loading an image from an API. You also have a `<Wrapper>` component that again has nothing to do with your question. By writing a separate piece of code, you can build up just the things that are required to illustrate your problem more clearly.

Comment: This process might even lead you to a solution on your own. But if not, you can [edit] your question to include the more simplified code and we can help you much more easily. For tips on creating a separate example, check out [mre].

Comment: @Code It simply means you did not even bother to read the complete sentence and replied just based on the title. The Wrapper is just one liner, used only for CSS. clickHandler() function is used to demonstrate the issue that I mentioned in the 1st part, to make people clear of what i am trying to do. So, I do not think it is unrelated or irrelevant part.